# Circles at the same height

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

How do I get the two circles to be on the same height? I tried the following

```
\newcommand{\sss}{\;\;\;\;\;\;\:}
\overset{\circ}{R}_{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}\overset{\circ\sss}{R^{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}} 
\overset{\circ}{R}_{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}\overset{\circ}{R}^{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

There is a command \mathring in LaTeX, try

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
\begin{displaymath}
\mathring{R}_{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda} \mathring{R}^{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You either need to add `amsmath` or eliminate the `*`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thanks, I changed it to LaTeX's displaymath

Comment: Or just `\[ .. \]`.

Answer (score 3):

Set the superscript *outside* the regular setting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\sss}{\;\;\;\;\;\;\:}

\begin{document} 

\[
  \overset{\circ}{R}_{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}\overset{\circ\sss}{R^{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}} \qquad
  \overset{\circ}{R}_{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}\overset{\circ}{R}^{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda} \qquad
  \overset{\circ}{R}_{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}\overset{\circ}{R}{}^{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}
\]

\end{document}
```